# is there a way to calculate a transaction change in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

| sender | reciever | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 30 |

The desired output should be:

| user | Trans_Change |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -20 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 |

i can't find a way to write a query for it in SQL.
the logic behind the desired output should be that;
1 sends 2 amount of 10, so now 1 has: -10 and 2 has: +10 and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Guess given known info:

We simply assign all senders negative transaction amounts union all the receivers as positive amounts and then group the data summing the transactions

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT sender as aUser, (-1 * amount) as Trans_Change -- Senders lose money
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT Receiver as aUser, amount -- receivers get money
FROM Table)

SELECT aUser, sum(Trans_Change) as Trans_Change -- aggregate transaction totals by user
FROM CTE
GROUP BY aUser
```

Part of addressing this is acknowledging that an amount is being used twice: once for the sender as a negative, once for a receiver as a positive (or credit/debit if you prefer)  Realizing this I knew I needed to get that value on two separate rows. selecting the data twice allowed for this. Using two selects and a union all allows us to get that value twice and then it's a  simple aggregration.

Comment: something isn't working, it gives an error: "Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.
" on the last GROUP BY clause

Comment: user is a reserved word I believe; let me change it to something else...  It's likely causing the issue... or you need to escape it appropriately for the RDBMS involved

Comment: Eat an elephant on bite at a time; break each problem down from a bigger problem into smaller ones.  I did this by getting all the minus to an user then all the adds to an user in two different datasets then combine and total them.  There may be a more elegant approach but I went for simple.

Comment: now when i figured out what you did, it's genius. THX

Comment: @aby_g never be afraid to ask for clairification on an answer someone provides.  If it works but you dont' understand it; our answer needs to be improved.  In the above I assumed you knew about CTE's .  I initiially didn't take the time to spell out why I took this approach.  But we should; not only to help you; but help others later.   Enjoy!